# How to serialize or convert Swift objects to JSON?

Tags: json, swift

This below class

```
class User: NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var id: Int
  @NSManaged var name: String
}
```

Needs to be converted to

```
{
    "id" : 98,
    "name" : "Jon Doe"
}
```

I tried manually passing the object to a function which sets the variables into a dictionary and returns the dictionary. But I would want a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: Your best bet is to run through it and save it to arrays and dicts, *then* convert.

Comment: Refer this - https://github.com/dankogai/swift-json

Comment: @Schemetrical could you point me to an example ? I don't know how to run through an object.

Comment: Well, you need to go through the object itself, take all the values, and add it to a dict manually, and repeat.

Comment: @Schemetrical I actually tried that. But for large objects compile time increases dramatically.

Comment: @redo1135 what are you even doing with your code? The compile time should not increase dramatically, I don't know what you're doing that increases compile time.

Comment: @Schemetrical I'm trying to send an object to my api. Object contains 21 values. I updated my question to include the function I'm using. Please let me know any improvements/suggestions

Answer (score 204, accepted):

In Swift 4, you can inherit from the `Codable` type.

```
struct Dog: Codable {
    var name: String
    var owner: String
}

// Encode
let dog = Dog(name: "Rex", owner: "Etgar")

let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(dog)
let json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

// Decode
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
let secondDog = try jsonDecoder.decode(Dog.self, from: jsonData)
```

Comment: The encoding type should be .utf8 instead of .utf16

Comment: @ChanJingHong it depends on what you’re trying to encode

Comment: For this specific example does .utf16 work? I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: @ChanJingHong Strange, I tried it 3 months ago and it worked. I think I should have put the encoding type also as an argument in the decoding method. I’ll check it out.

Comment: What if you have a series objects of various types? You don't know much about the types except they are all Codable. Is there a way to handle this situation?

Comment: It would be nice if you mentioned jsonString to jsonData conversion step @Etgar

Comment: Doesn't this assume you have control over the object's class definition? This often isn't the case.

Comment: question was specifically about encoding `class` (what I need) not `struct`.

Comment: @gondo this will work with both class and struct as well

Comment: @NishadArora classes behave differently than structs. f.e. you can't assign custom name to struct via `@objc(MyName)`. I stand by my point, the question was about class not struct

Answer (score 55):

Along with Swift 4 (Foundation) now it is natively supported in both ways, JSON string to an object - an object to JSON string.
Please see Apple's documentation here [JSONDecoder()](https://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj1jfLXrt_WAhWhJ5oKHbdEBswQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fdocumentation%2Ffoundation%2Fjsondecoder&usg=AOvVaw3pEVqYlT3Rzz9K-ZJBa8fR) and here [JSONEncoder()](https://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj654zqrt_WAhWFO5oKHRwaD-8QFggzMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fdocumentation%2Ffoundation%2Fjsonencoder&usg=AOvVaw2-O8e-qf9HdihmrOVpzKO-)

JSON String to Object

```
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let myStruct = try! decoder.decode(myStruct.self, from: jsonData)
```

Swift Object to JSONString

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
let data = try! encoder.encode(myStruct)
print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

Comment: Link is broken..

Answer (score 28):

**UPDATE:** `Codable` protocol introduced in Swift 4 should be sufficient for most of the `JSON` parsing cases. Below answer is for people who are stuck in previous versions of Swift and for legacy reasons

**[EVReflection](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection) :**

- This works of reflection principle. This takes less code and also supports `NSDictionary`, `NSCoding`, `Printable`, `Hashable` and `Equatable`

**Example:**

```
    class User: EVObject { # extend EVObject method for the class
       var id: Int = 0
       var name: String = ""
       var friends: [User]? = []
    }

    # use like below
    let json:String = "{\"id\": 24, \"name\": \"Bob Jefferson\", \"friends\": [{\"id\": 29, \"name\": \"Jen Jackson\"}]}"
    let user = User(json: json)
```

**[ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) :**

- Another way is by using ObjectMapper. This gives more control but also takes a lot more code.

**Example:**

```
    class User: Mappable { # extend Mappable method for the class
       var id: Int?
       var name: String?

       required init?(_ map: Map) {

       }

       func mapping(map: Map) { # write mapping code
          name    <- map["name"]
          id      <- map["id"]
       }

    }

    # use like below
    let json:String = "{\"id\": 24, \"name\": \"Bob Jefferson\", \"friends\": [{\"id\": 29, \"name\": \"Jen Jackson\"}]}"
    let user = Mapper<User>().map(json)
```

Comment: Does it supports mapping images also??

Comment: @Charlie sorry I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: @ Suresh: It is possible by writing custom transform as shown examples. I converted the image to String and then added  in Json object. It helps a lot specially working with watch os

Comment: Hi, do you know how to initialize a Mappable class and set properties manually and then convert object to jsonString?

Comment: what is the impact of codeable protocol from swift 4/ ios 11?? . Can we convert NSManagedObject to JSON in swift 4 using this??

Comment: If you are using ObjectMapper, you can reduce a lot of boilerplate code by using [BetterMappable][1] which is written over ObjectMapper using PropertyWrappers. You need to be on Swift 5.1 to use it.


  [1]: https://github.com/PhonePe/BetterMappable

Answer (score 15):

I worked a bit on a smaller solution that doesn't require inheritance. But it hasn't been tested much. It's pretty ugly atm.

https://github.com/peheje/JsonSerializerSwift

You can pass it into a playground to test it. E.g. following class structure:

```
//Test nonsense data
class Nutrient {
    var name = "VitaminD"
    var amountUg = 4.2

    var intArray = [1, 5, 9]
    var stringArray = ["nutrients", "are", "important"]
}

class Fruit {
    var name: String = "Apple"
    var color: String? = nil
    var weight: Double = 2.1
    var diameter: Float = 4.3
    var radius: Double? = nil
    var isDelicious: Bool = true
    var isRound: Bool? = nil
    var nullString: String? = nil
    var date = NSDate()

    var optionalIntArray: Array<Int?> = [1, 5, 3, 4, nil, 6]
    var doubleArray: Array<Double?> = [nil, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]
    var stringArray: Array<String> = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
    var optionalArray: Array<Int> = [2, 4, 1]

    var nutrient = Nutrient()
}

var fruit = Fruit()
var json = JSONSerializer.toJson(fruit)

print(json)
```

prints

```
{"name": "Apple", "color": null, "weight": 2.1, "diameter": 4.3, "radius": null, "isDelicious": true, "isRound": null, "nullString": null, "date": "2015-06-19 22:39:20 +0000", "optionalIntArray": [1, 5, 3, 4, null, 6], "doubleArray": [null, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4], "stringArray": ["one", "two", "three", "four"], "optionalArray": [2, 4, 1], "nutrient": {"name": "VitaminD", "amountUg": 4.2, "intArray": [1, 5, 9], "stringArray": ["nutrients", "are", "important"]}}
```

Comment: can you please provide its swift 2.3 version?

Comment: Looks awesome, but it doesn't work with SPM...

Answer (score 10):

This is not a perfect/automatic solution but I believe this is the **idiomatic and native** way to do such. This way you don't need any libraries or such.

Create an protocol such as:

```
/// A generic protocol for creating objects which can be converted to JSON
protocol JSONSerializable {
    private var dict: [String: Any] { get }
}

extension JSONSerializable {
    /// Converts a JSONSerializable conforming class to a JSON object.
    func json() rethrows -> Data {
        try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self.dict, options: nil)
    }
}
```

Then implement it in your class such as:

```
class User: JSONSerializable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String

    var dict { return ["id": self.id, "name": self.name]  }
}
```

Now:

```
let user = User(...)
let json = user.json()
```

Note: if you want `json` as a string, it is very simply to convert to a string: `String(data: json, encoding .utf8)`

Answer (score 8):

Some of the above answers are completely fine, but I added an extension here, just to make it much more readable and usable.

```
extension Encodable {
    var convertToString: String? {
        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        jsonEncoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
        do {
            let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(self)
            return String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

struct User: Codable {
     var id: Int
     var name: String
}

let user = User(id: 1, name: "name")
print(user.convertToString!)
```

//This will print like the following:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "name"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
struct User:Codable{
 var id:String?
 var name:String?
 init(_ id:String,_ name:String){
   self.id  = id
   self.name = name
 }
}
```

> Now just make your object like this

let user = User("1","pawan")

```
do{
      let userJson =  try JSONEncoder().encode(parentMessage) 
            
    }catch{
         fatalError("Unable To Convert in Json")      
    }
```

> Then reconvert from json to Object

```
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
do{
   let convertedUser = try jsonDecoder.decode(User.self, from: userJson.data(using: .utf8)!)
 }catch{
   
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

## 2021 | SWIFT 5.1 | Results solution

Data sample:

```
struct ConfigCreds: Codable { // Codable is important!
    // some params
}
```

Solution usage sample:

```
var configCreds = ConfigCreds()
var jsonStr: String = ""

// Object -> JSON
configCreds
   .asJson()
   .onSuccess { jsonStr = $0 }
   .onFailure { _ in // any failure code }

// JSON -> object of type "ConfigCreds"
someJsonString
    .decodeFromJson(type: ConfigCreds.self)
    .onSuccess { configCreds = $0 }
    .onFailure { _ in // any failure code }
```

Back-End code:

```
@available(macOS 10.15, *)
public extension Encodable {
    func asJson() -> Result<String, Error>{
        JSONEncoder()
            .try(self)
            .flatMap{ $0.asString() }
    }
}

public extension String {
    func decodeFromJson<T>(type: T.Type) -> Result<T, Error> where T: Decodable {
        self.asData()
            .flatMap { JSONDecoder().try(type, from: $0) }
    }
}

///////////////////////////////
/// HELPERS
//////////////////////////////

@available(macOS 10.15, *)
fileprivate extension JSONEncoder {
    func `try`<T : Encodable>(_ value: T) -> Result<Output, Error> {
        do {
            return .success(try self.encode(value))
        } catch {
            return .failure(error)
        }
    }
}

fileprivate extension JSONDecoder {
    func `try`<T: Decodable>(_ t: T.Type, from data: Data) -> Result<T,Error> {
        do {
            return .success(try self.decode(t, from: data))
        } catch {
            return .failure(error)
        }
    }
}

fileprivate extension String {
    func asData() -> Result<Data, Error> {
        if let data = self.data(using: .utf8) {
            return .success(data)
        } else {
            return .failure(WTF("can't convert string to data: \(self)"))
        }
    }
}

fileprivate extension Data {
    func asString() -> Result<String, Error> {
        if let str = String(data: self, encoding: .utf8) {
            return .success(str)
        } else {
            return .failure(WTF("can't convert Data to string"))
        }
    }
}

fileprivate func WTF(_ msg: String, code: Int = 0) -> Error {
    NSError(code: code, message: msg)
}

internal extension NSError {
    convenience init(code: Int, message: String) {
        let userInfo: [String: String] = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:message]
        self.init(domain: "FTW", code: code, userInfo: userInfo)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how to use this. IDE errors with "Value of type 'JSONEncoder.Output' has no member 'asString'" and "Value of type 'String' has no member 'asData'"

Comment: @DevinM by the way, I have fixed the code here

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if lib/framework exists, but if you would like to do it automatically and you would like to avoid manual labour :-) stick with `MirrorType` ...

```
class U {

  var id: Int
  var name: String

  init(id: Int, name: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
  }

}

extension U {

  func JSONDictionary() -> Dictionary<String, Any> {
    var dict = Dictionary<String, Any>()

    let mirror = reflect(self)

    var i: Int
    for i = 0 ; i < mirror.count ; i++ {
      let (childName, childMirror) = mirror[i]

      // Just an example how to check type
      if childMirror.valueType is String.Type {
        dict[childName] = childMirror.value
      } else if childMirror.valueType is Int.Type {
        // Convert to NSNumber for example
        dict[childName] = childMirror.value
      }
    }

    return dict
  }

}
```

Take it as a rough example, lacks proper conversion support, lacks recursion, ... It's just `MirrorType` demonstration ...

P.S. Here it's done in `U`, but you're going to enhance `NSManagedObject` and then you'll be able to convert all `NSManagedObject` subclasses. No need to implement this in all subclasses/managed objects.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying this method, but every time I'm getting 0 as the count. Could you be more specific as to what I should do ? I think @NSManaged is causing problems. How do I enhance NSManagedObject ?

Comment: Didn't try with `@NSManaged`. Maybe it's causing your problem. In this case, I would write it in Objective-C and then will use it from Swift.