# Is SwiftyJson capable of converting a custom swift class to a json string?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

Given below is my custom swift class. My Question is how to convert an object of this class to a json string using SwiftyJson?

```
class Equipment{

    var UniqueItemId:String? = ""
    var ItemNo:String? = ""
    var EquipmentType:String? = ""
    var EquipmentDescription:String? = ""
    var Length:String? = ""
    var Wll:String? = ""
    var  EquipmentLocation:String? = ""
    var EquipmentManufacture:String? = ""
    var SerialNo:String? = ""
    var Condition:String? = ""
    var Remarks:String? = ""
    var InspectionDate:String? = ""
    var Inspector:String? = ""

}
```

For example, like this:

```
var jsonString = JSON(equipmentObject);
```

Comment: You question is misframed: SwiftlyJson is a library that *reads* JSON. It does not *produce* JSON.

Comment: if you are looking for functionality like GSON for java, i dont think you can do that in swift

Comment: @Gwendal Roué: goodness.. I was totally lost. Thank you so much for the  heads up, is there any other alternative in swift to do this?

Comment: @Fonix Thanks. Yes I need a solution that works in swift

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert swift objects to Json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599005/convert-swift-objects-to-json)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**

OP is now happy with [EVReflection](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection). So I assume that at this moment it's the best choice.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Since Swift reflection possibilities is not yet such rich there is no ultimate solution now like [google-gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for Java.

Libraries like [SwiftJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) and [Swift ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) are just sugared `NSJSONSerialization` and require you to define mappings from json fields to object properties.

But things are changing and you can try out [JsonSerializerSwift](https://github.com/peheje/JsonSerializerSwift). I have not yet used it but it use Swift reflection and seems to work fine.

Also check out [Swift Mirrors and JSON by Chris Eidhof](http://chris.eidhof.nl/posts/swift-mirrors-and-json.html) article. It explains how JSON serialization using reflection possibilities works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This explains almost all the options that I've here. I'll try to use JsonSerializerSwift.

Comment: It looks like JsonSerializerSwift has some issues with converting complex objects that contains nested objects in them. The best alternative I came up with is "EVReflection" (https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection). Can convert object->json and Json->object as well.  This works like a charm.

Comment: Thx! I added link to my answer.

Comment: Asa: I would like to improve upon JsonSerializerSwift. Would you mind elaborating on the data structure that causes the problems? I'm on Twitter.

Answer (score 3):

May be this will helps: https://github.com/PonyCui/PPJSONSerialization

You use serialize to serialize PPJSONSerialization classes to JSON String or JSON Data, it's a perfect way to deliver data to server.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4, there's now the Codable framework that's baked in. From my research this is the best option for those who can upgrade to the latest version of the language.

If the property names are identical it's just a few lines to call up a json decoder, and if they're different you just have to write a small switch statement to map them.

I'm sure in the coming months a library will pop up to take care of standard mapping situations but other than that things are looking pretty good out of the box.

check it here: http://benscheirman.com/2017/06/ultimate-guide-to-json-parsing-with-swift-4/

Answer (score 1):

From Swift4 we can use **JSONEncoder** itself to convert Object model to Json String.

For that we just needs to extends the Object with **Codable** if the json keys are standard.

Reference :

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/using_json_with_custom_types