# Find special characters entered in a textfield and escape in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

My requirement is to create a `JSON` from the text entered in a `UITextField`. There is no restriction to the `UITextField`. So, if a user enters a special character(", \ etc.), I want to escape the value entered and create a `JSON`.

> String literals can include the following special characters:
>
> - The escaped special characters \0 (null character), \ (backslash), \t (horizontal tab), \n (line feed), \r (carriage return), \"
>     (double quote) and \' (single quote)
> - An arbitrary Unicode scalar, written as \u{n}, where n is a 1–8 digit hexadecimal number with a value equal to a valid Unicode code
>     point

For example, if the user enters `"Hello "User"! How to use a \ in a JSON?"`. It should return something like this `"Hello \"User\"! How to use a \\ in a JSON?"`. Not just " or \, I would want to escape all the special characters.

Thanks! I truly appreciate your effort in providing me with a solution.

**Edit**
I forgot to mention, this requirement is for Swift 4.2.

Comment: What have you tried? In what context do you want to achieve this? Having `struct Data { var input : String }` and then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599005/how-to-serialize-or-convert-swift-objects-to-json should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not “manually” escape the characters in order to create JSON. There is a dedicated `JSONEncoder()` class for this purpose.

Top-level JSON objects can only be arrays or dictionaries. Here is an example for an array containing a single element with the given string:

```
let text = """
    Hello "User"! How to use a \\ in a JSON?
    Another line line
    """

do {
    let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode([text])
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
    print(jsonString)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

The output is

```
["Hello \"User\"! How to use a \\ in a JSON?\nAnother line"]
```

Comment: Have you tried this? This does not work ->

`let valueString = #"{"value": "testing a \ and a " also an & with { value }"}"#
print(valueString)
do {
 let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(valueString)
 let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
 print(jsonString)
} catch {
 print(error.localizedDescription)
}`

Comment: @avrospirit: As I said, you have to embed the string in an array or dictionary: `JSONEncoder().encode([valueString])`

Comment: He's not using Swift 5, so example might want to remove `#` and use `\\`.

Comment: @avrospirit: I have “downgraded” the code for Swift 4.2. Please let me know if there are still problems.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR. I missed the embedding part in the string.