# Convert NSObject to JSON serializable?

Tags: swift

I'm getting a result and I'm trying to make it JSON serializable, which probably mean to convert it from NSObject to Object. Is that possible? I've checked Codable, but I didn't understand what I'm supposed to do. My result could change in the future (types, keys, values, etc).

**dump(result):**

```
{ test1: 123, test2: () }> #0
  - super: NSObject
```

---

**Edit:**

```java
let result = appleIDCredential
let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(result)
let json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

**Returns:**

> Argument type 'ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential' does not conform to
>   expected type 'Encodable'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serialize and deserialize NSObjects with this useful framework.
HandyJSON is a framework written in Swift which to make converting model objects( pure classes/structs ) to and from JSON easy.
https://cocoapods.org/pods/HandyJSON

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Is there any way I can serialize/deserialize without any external frameworks? Thanks!

Comment: I think it is but in Swift 4. Here is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599005/how-to-serialize-or-convert-swift-objects-to-json

Comment: I've edited my initial question with the `JSONEncoder` stuff. Now it throws an error `Argument type 'ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential' does not conform to expected type 'Encodable'`. I guess it's because I didn't make the object Codable, I'm not sure how to do it..