# Initialize Swift class with AnyObject? from NSJSONSerialization

Tags: json, swift, enums, option-type, nsjsonserialization

I am using `NSJSONSerialization` in Swift 1.2 to parse some json that is returned from an API response.

```
var err: NSError?
let opts = NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments
let json: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: opts, error: &err)
```

The parsed json is provided as `AnyObject?`. I would like to use this optional to initialize a class object which can be used as the model data in an application.

```
class Alerts {
    let type: String
    let date: String
    let description: String
    let expires: String
    let message: String

    init(json: AnyObject) {
        if let
        jsonDict = json as? [String: AnyObject],
        alertsArray = jsonDict["alerts"] as? [AnyObject],
        alertsDict = alertsArray[0] as? [String: AnyObject],
        type = alertsDict["type"] as? String,
        date = alertsDict["date"] as? String,
        description = alertsDict["description"] as? String,
        expires = alertsDict["expires"] as? String,
        message = alertsDict["message"] as? String
        {
            self.type = type
            self.date = date
            self.description = description
            self.expires = expires
            self.message = message
        }
        else
        {
            self.type = "err"
            self.date = "err"
            self.description = "err"
            self.expires = "err"
            self.message = "err"
        }
    }
}

// example of creating a data model from the json
let alerts = Alerts(json: json!)
alerts.type
alerts.date
alerts.description
alerts.expires
alerts.message
```

Since `NSJSONSerialization` returns an optional, I have to check for the existence of each value type as I extract the json data. As you can see in the above code, I used the improved optional bindings from Swift 1.2 to clean up the `init` method. Without using third-party libraries, is there anything else I can do to the class model (`enums`, `structs`, `type aliases`) to make it more readable?  Should I use a `struct` for the model data instead of a `class`?  Would it be possible to create a custom type using an `enum` or `struct` to represent a json object?

Comment: I know you mentioned you didn't want to use third party libraries but I really think you should take a look at SwiftyJSON. It checks everything for you and gives you a nested dictionary. Personally, I would then use this to map the JSON to a swift model using Structs, assingning data in the init and nesting the Structs appropriating staring from something like "Root()" and going down from there.

Comment: @Cole I'm aware of SwiftyJSON and Argo, but I do not want to depend on them. Using a `struct` instead of a `class` for the swift model may be a good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

So without using third party libraries, the `if let` trees are usually the best practice, which you have shown. To help you later down the road, maybe recreate your object hierarchy in JSON as a Struct model in Swift. Something like:

```
var json = JSON(JSONData.sharedjson.jsonRaw!)
var mongoIdTest = json["resultset"]["account"]["mongoId"].string

struct Root {
    var timestamp: Int?
    var resultset = ResultSet()

    init() {
        self.timestamp = json["timestamp"].int
        println(json)
    }

}

struct ResultSet {
    var alert: String?

    var account = Account()
    var customer = Customer()

    init() {

    }


}

struct Account {
    var mongoId: String?

    init() {
        mongoId = json["resultset"]["account"]["mongoId"].string
    }
}

struct Locations {

}

struct Customer {
    var account: String?
    var address: String?
    var id: String?
    var loginId: String?
    var mongoId: String?
    var name: String?

    var opco = Opco()

    init() {
        account = json["resultset"]["customer"]["account"].string
        address = json["resultset"]["customer"]["address"].string
        id = json["resultset"]["customer"]["id"].string
        loginId = json["resultset"]["customer"]["loginId"].string
        mongoId = json["resultset"]["customer"]["mongoId"].string
        name = json["resultset"]["customer"]["name"].string
    }

}

struct Opco {
    var id: String?
    var phone: String?
    var cutOffTime: String?
    var name: String?
    var payerId: String?

    init() {
        id = json["resultset"]["customer"]["opco"]["id"].string
        phone = json["resultset"]["customer"]["opco"]["phone"].string
        cutOffTime = json["resultset"]["customer"]["opco"]["cutOffTime"].string
        name = json["resultset"]["customer"]["opco"]["name"].string
        payerId = json["resultset"]["customer"]["opco"]["payerId"].string
    }
}
```

This way you can still use autocomplete and dot notation to navigate through your hierarchy.

Edit: I have a data structure from an actual project I've worked on added to the answer, hopefully this gives a better idea. Keep in mind that I'm using SwiftyJSON for the `JSON()` call.

Edit 2:

This is a method I found for getting JSON info into a Swift dictionary without the use of some other library. I'm not sure there is another way to do it that's easier without the use of third party libraries.

```
var urlToRequest = "https://EXAMPLE.com/api/account.login?username=MY_USERNAME&password=Hunter2"

if let json = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest)!) {

    // Parse JSON to Dictionary
    var error: NSError?
    let boardsDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(json, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    fulljson = boardsDictionary

    // Display all keys and values
    println("Keys in User Data:")
    for (key, value) in boardsDictionary! {
        println("\(key)-------\(value)")
    }

    println(fulljson?["resultset"])
}
else {
    println("Test JSON nil: No Connection?")
}
```

That dictionary will be the input for your Structs.

Comment: Can elaborate on what you mean by using a `struct` for the object hierarchy?

Comment: You're still using a third-party library, SwiftyJSON.  As my question stated, I would like to avoid using someone else's library to parse json.

Comment: I know, that was only a sample of using structs. In their initializers, you can assign values any way you want, I just used SwiftyJSON because that's how I originally wrote it. Regardless, `mongoId = json["resultset"]["account"]["mongoId"].string` could easily be `mongoId = JSONDictionary["resultset"]["account"]["mongoId"]` where `let JSONDictionary: Dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: nil, error: &error) as NSDictionary`

Comment: The point is to turn a Dictionary into easily readable and accessible data. See this link for more info on parsing JSON directly into a dictionary. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310324/deserialize-json-nsdictionary-to-swift-objects

Comment: All of the examples in the link use third-party libraries too.  I'm starting to think that there is just no easy way to handle json in Swift.

Comment: I've tried one more thing that may work for you. Check my answer for more details.