# How do I set a value of a variable to an array within a dictionaries key value?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have stored a users home address in firebase as an array. It looks like this:

[image: Image for User Home Address]

I am now trying to grab all of my users data and store them into a dictionary like this:

[image: Image for Storing in a Dictionary]

The `User()` part of the code is defined above like this:

```
var users = [User]()
```

the `[User]()` part of it comes from a user.swift file which is here:

```
class User: NSObject {
    var fullName: String?
    var email: String!
    var userPhoto: String?
    var homeAddress: [String:[Double]]()
    var schoolOrWorkAddress: String!
}
```

the error is with the `homeAddress` part of it.

In the file I create variables for all my user data storage. My question now is how do I set home address to a value type of an array as that dictionaries key value. Can anyone help? Feel free to comment if you have any questions in helping me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34466568/6297658

Comment: PS: The home address acts as a key in the dictionary. I am struggling to set the value of that key which is an array of 2 coordinates.

Comment: Hi, I am new to swift and would love if you could show me how that links answer works?

Comment: Give your JSON tree , as text not an image, Also if you r new to Swift might i suggest you use `struct` instead of class and made an variable of type `struct_name` and called it to initialise your values which you'll have to retrieve separately

Comment: Never mind I figured it our. I simply had to do this: var homeAddress: NSArray

Answer (score 0):

You could try to override the setValue function to iterate through homeAddress points.

```
// value in this case would be the points in your dictionary and the
// the key would be "homeAddress"
override func setValue(value: AnyObject?, forKey key: String) {
    if key == "homeAddress" {

        let homeAddressPoints = [HomeAddressPoint]()
        for dict in value as! [[String: AnyObject]] {
            let point = HomeAddressPoint()
            point.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dict)
            homeAddressPoints?.append(point)
        }

    } else {
        super.setValue(value, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

This is just an idea, and hopefully you can build from this.

Comment: **Do not** override KVC methods unless you really need KVC which is not the case in this example.