# Convert Json to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, nsdictionary

I am trying to convert serialized `Json` string to `NSDictionary` but not find any solution to convert serialized `Json` to `NSDictionary`.

This is my response string

```
{"id":2,"parent_id":1,"lft":2,"rght":3,"name":"Audio Engineering","images":[{"id":22,"user_id":2,"name":"iStock_000027023404_Small","url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/97601593\/Picture_3_400x400.png","alt":"iStock_000027023404_Small","description":"","thumbnail":"a:3:{i:0;a:4:{s:4:\"name\";s:25:\"iStock_000027023404_Small\";s:5:\"width\";i:30;s:6:\"height\";i:30;s:3:\"url\";s:58:\"\/uploads\/2016\/09\/thumb\/small\/iStock_000027023404_Small.jpg\";}i:1;a:4:{s:4:\"name\";s:25:\"iStock_000027023404_Small\";s:5:\"width\";i:90;s:6:\"height\";i:90;s:3:\"url\";s:59:\"\/uploads\/2016\/09\/thumb\/medium\/iStock_000027023404_Small.jpg\";}i:2;a:4:{s:4:\"name\";s:25:\"iStock_000027023404_Small\";s:5:\"width\";i:230;s:6:\"height\";i:230;s:3:\"url\";s:67:\"\/uploads\/2016\/09\/thumb\/medium_251x230\/iStock_000027023404_Small.jpg\";}}","created":"2016-09-07T06:24:09+00:00","modified":"2016-09-07T06:24:09+00:00","_joinData":{"id":12,"category_id":2,"image_id":22}}]}
```

Which I am trying to convert to `NSDictionary`. In this value for key `Thumbnail` is serialized data which I am not able to parse.

I have tried

```
NSData *data = [[self getJsonnResponse] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&error];

if (error)
    NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
else
    NSLog(@"%@",json);
```

It throws me error

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Badly formed object around character 291." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed object around character 291.}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON / NSDictionary to Swift objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310324/deserialize-json-nsdictionary-to-swift-objects)

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: your thumbnail is string, it contains JSON String

Comment: hey pls check my updated question

Comment: #Dejan Skledar the question in link does not provide the solution to my question as question in link is to convert Json or NSDictionary to Swift obj but my question is how to convert the above string to NSDictionary and fetch the Thumbnail contents.

Comment: @PradumnaPatil - are you there

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes

Comment: @PradumnaPatil - are you found the issue , and yiour issue resolved or not

Comment: Not not yet still searching for the solution.

Comment: is my provided answer helped or not ?

Answer (score 1):

*character **291*** means the character at index **291**. on JSON Response

your problem is here , is not a valid part

`"thumbnail":"a:3:{i:0;a:4:{s:4:\"name\";s:25:\"iStock_000027023404_Small\";s:5:\"width\";i:30;s:6:\"height\";i:30;s:3:\"url\";s:58:\"\/uploads\/2016\/09\/thumb\/small\/iStock_000027023404_Small.jpg\";}i:1;a:4:{s:4:\"name\";s:25:\"iStock_000027023404_Small\";s:5:\"width\";i:90;s:6:\"height\";i:90;s:3:\"url\";s:59:\"\/uploads\/2016\/09\/thumb\/medium\/iStock_000027023404_Small.jpg\";}i:2;a:4:{s:4:\"name\";s:25:\"iStock_000027023404_Small\";s:5:\"width\";i:230;s:6:\"height\";i:230;s:3:\"url\";s:67:\"\/uploads\/2016\/09\/thumb\/medium_251x230\/iStock_000027023404_Small.jpg\";}}`

check once in back end and ask the clear format of JSON

Answer (score 1):

This one is wrong `json` formate and what I see here is may be your web developer put log to check `array` and `dictionary` is generation proper or not.
Please ask web developer to resolve this issue.

**your `Thumbnail` proposed `JSON` is like this:**

```
{
    {
        "name": "iStock_000027023404_Small";
        "width": 30;
        "height": 30;
        "url": "/uploads/2016/09/thumb/small/iStock_000027023404_Small.jpg";
    } {
        "name": "iStock_000027023404_Small";
        "width": 90;
        "height": 90;
        "url": "/uploads/2016/09/thumb/medium/iStock_000027023404_Small.jpg";
    } {
        "name": "iStock_000027023404_Small";
        "width": 230;
        "height": 230;
        "url": "/uploads/2016/09/thumb/medium_251x230/iStock_000027023404_Small.jpg";
    }
}
```

May be it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

once check the json objcet is valid or not before parsing using the help of following method

```
 NSData *data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:data]) {
    // here parse your json data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to convert json to dictionary.

NSError * err;

NSData *data =[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary * responseDict;

if(data!=nil)
{

responseDict = (NSDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];

}

return responseDict;